# How do I get a  UDTT704D USB tv tuner working?

Tags: usb, tv-tuner, mythtv

I am a new Linux user. I have an UDTT704D USB TV tuner but I can't watch TV on my Ubuntu install. I have tried several different viewers like Kaffeine and MythTV but they don't identify my tuner. `lsusb` says the tuner is connected. What should I do if I want to use my tuner card in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

- OS: Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit
- Kernel: Linux 3.0.0-14-generic
- GNOME: 3.2.1
- Output of `lsusb`:

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:3213 IMC Networks DTV-DVB UDTT704D - DVBT/NTSC/PAL Driver (PCM4)
  ```
- Output of `hwinfo --usb --short`:

  ```
  unknown: DVB 704DTVBꀀX
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Hello! Ubuntu 11.10 Kernel: Linux 3.0.0-14-generic GNOME 3.2.1 lsusb: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:3213 IMC Networks DTV-DVB UDTT704D - DVBT/NTSC/PAL Driver (PCM4) hwinfo --usb --short: unknown:
                       DVB 704DTVBꀀX

Comment: Im afraid I cant use this tuner in Ubuntu.
Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page is the authoritative resource for TV on Linux.

See if you can spot your device being supported at http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hardware_Device_Information

If not then I'm afraid it's game over unless you can find someone to write you a driver (not trivial) :)

My initial quick scan of that site and the general Internet suggests no, it's not supported.

(I realise it's not optimal to just link to answers but copying a Wiki into Ask Ubuntu isn't a productive use of time either) ;)